Access mutable cache in recursive context
I have the following code
fn foo(value: &String, cache: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) {
    // values are inserted but never modified
    cache.insert("a", vec!["b".to_string()]);
    if let Some(cached_result) = cache.get(value) {
        // let cached_result = cached_result.clone();
        cached_result
            .iter()
            .for_each(|cached_value| foo(cached_value, cache));
    }
}

This is a minimized and completely artificial example of the issue I'm trying to understand.
In the code above, the borrow checker complains with:
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `*cache` but it is already borrowed
 --> src/day11.rs:8:23
  |
4 |     if let Some(cached_result) = cache.get(value) {
  |                                  ----- borrow occurs here
...
8 |             .for_each(|cached_value| foo(cached_value, cache));
  |              -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   ----- second borrow occurs due to use of `*cache` in closure
  |              |        |
  |              |        closure construction occurs here
  |              first borrow later used by call

What I understand is that

cache holds ownership of its values
we theoretically could modify the cached_result downstream, so we can't safely pass it there while still iterating over it

The problem is that in my real code I never modify the values, I only insert into the cache.
Cloning the cached_result solves the problem, but I don't want to do that.
How should I structure the code, so that I can have a mutable cache with immutable values inside and be able to use that cache while iterating over the value?

https://docs.rs/elsa/latest/elsa/map/struct.FrozenMap.html

Your function is strangely backwards. Normally a cache would be used to look up the result of a function and return it, and otherwise do some costly computation. In your example the only outside effect is building up cache. So the solution is probably to redesign it.

@starblue hence my comment about the artificiality of the example. I removed everything not related to the compiler error. The solution made sense in the original context. I believe having granular control over mutability is not an uncommon scenario.

Look at the library I linked.

cache doesn't need to be &mut in this example, you're not mutating it. I assume you accidentally removed that part, but it's important in understanding the problem.

Could you clarify which part of the cache foo should modify? The example as given only ever observes values, but never acts on cache itself. Does only insert into the cache mean pushing onto Vec<String>, or does it mean adding to cache for a new key?

Yes, I might have minimized it too much. The cache is modified by adding new values to the map. I will try to amend the example

@Krever notice that inserting value into hashmap may re-allocate, which in turn will invalidate all existing references (while you are iterating over it using for_each). So it its impossible to perform this algorithm you showed with hashmap from std.

Replace your Strings with Rc<str> or Arc<str> which can be cloned safely and cheaply (since it only increments the refcount without copying the data).

When you call foo, do you intend the for_each to loop over only the original items present, or do you intend the for_each to include the dynamically inserted key/value pairs during iteration? The answer will depend on that choice.

Only the ones present when starting the iteration

My suggestion would be to use an Atomic Reference Counter (Arc), so you avoid real cloning, but instead do increase a reference counter to the same data point in memory.
Since you are literally only reading that should be enough and avoid performance penalty of data cloning. To also improve safety between threads you could introduce a Mutex in the Arc, but you might not require it.
The code could look like this, based on your conceptual snippet:
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc};

fn foo(value: &String, cache: &mut HashMap<String, Arc<Vec<String>>>) {
    // values are inserted but never modified
    cache.insert("a".into(), Arc::new(vec!["b".to_string()]));
    if let Some(cached_result) = cache.get(value) {
        cached_result.clone()
            .iter()
            .for_each(|cached_value| foo(cached_value, cache));
    }
}

To understand more about Arc (and Mutex,...) check official docs here.
Hope this helps!
